# Redis Server docker container connect to another docker container can only work with bind all

Tags: redis, docker

When content of `/host/redis.conf` is `bind 0.0.0.0`,

```
docker run --name some-redis -d -v /host/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -v /host/redis_data:/disk -p 6379:6379 redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Then connect from another docker container with `docker-cli`, it works.

But when anything than that, redis server does not even want to run.

For example, running it with `bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.59.103` gives me:

```
Creating Server TCP listening socket 172.0.0.1:6379: bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

And if I set it to `bind 192.168.59.103` gives me:

```
Creating Server TCP listening socket 192.168.59.103:6379: bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

By the way if you want to test this, error message can only be outputted by running:

```
$ID(docker run --name some-redis -d -v /host/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -v /host/redis_data:/disk -p 6379:6379 redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf)
docker logs $ID
```

I've been working on this bug for too long. Please help.